# Project split and composition

Tags: java, android

I want to write a android app with my team, but because we are not always together and far away, we want to give each piece of work to one person, and whoever pushes forward some of the project and eventually connects everyone. And merge
I mean, for example, divide the project into 5 parts and give it to 5 people, then combine these 5 parts into a project.
Is this possible? How can I do this?

Comment: Are we talking about git here or I am understanding something wrong?

Comment: whats the git ? its just about android app development

Comment: It's unclear, you want to merge all work in the same project or you want to split the architecture of the app so each team is independent of the source code?

Comment: its clear bro i want to first split the app and final after each part completed merge to 1 project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Version Control System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control). There are a lot of them available, and I'm not going to list them all. [svn](https://subversion.apache.org/) and [git](https://git-scm.com/) are two of the popular ones.

You're going to need a central repo for this though. There's i.e. [Github](https://github.com) and [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), though you could also host your own server (assuming you're familiar with servers) and use something like Gitlab.

Version Control Systems have a bunch of features like merging and branches, which is why it's easier using a VCS for collaboration compared to splitting up projects and sharing the files

Comment: can you please explain more because im a little bit new on this work